# Batch rename files using CSV list?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have CSV list with 2 columns where the first column is new filename and second column is present filename. Files that I need to rename are jpg without extension. Also, they are inside subfolder.
CSV is as this:

```
image 123.jpg,1a02fb0a
image 234.jpg,43beb7e8
image xyz.jpg,388f5181
```

They are without quotes.

Trying this ren command:

```
FOR /f "delims=; tokens=1,2" %A in (ren.csv) do @ren "%~B" "%~A"
```

I got

```
SYSTEM CANNOT FIND FILE SPECIFIED
```

Also tried with no result:

```
FOR /f "delims=; tokens=1,2" %%G in (ren.csv) do @ren "%~B" "%~A"
```

Comment: I've done similar things in the past, but in a different way : I modified my CSV-file into a batchfile, containing lines like: `move 1a02fb0a image_123.jpg`, and then I launched that batchfile. In that way, I could easily test it (just launching the first line and see what happens) and once correct, I just launched that batchfile. For your information, text editors like Notepad++ and Ultra Edit have column editing and macros for doing stuff like this.

Comment: You've got `C`omma-`S`eparated `V`alues, yet have inexplicably decided to use semicolons as your delimiters. If you're not sure what the `Delims` option does, enter `For /?` at the Command Prompt and read the output.

Comment: Why did you set your delimiter to be semi-colon `;`, when your list is separated by commas (`,`)??  In your second attempt, your iterator variable is `%G`, but you refer to `%A` and `%B`.  Your code make no sense!!

Answer (score 1):

Your command has a portion: `"delims=;"`, which says, *"Look for a ; as a separator"*.

But your file, `ren.csv`, has a ***COMMA*** (`,`) as a separator, not a semi-colon.

When I used this command, it worked fine.

```
FOR /f "delims=, tokens=1,2" %A in (ren.csv) do @echo "%~B" "%~A"
```

Comment: I Can see that error with separator, now I managed to rename. The problem I have now is that special characters in new filenames are not copied correctly. CSV file is in UTF-8, when I open it every character is displayed OK but when files are renamed they are not, any way to solve this?